# What is the Japanese word or phrase for "to post on the internet"?

Tags: word-requests

How do you say "to post something on the Internet"?  Are there different words for different kinds of posts, for example:

- a blog entry
- a comment
- a piece of information, like a translation or a recipe
- a video or photo
- etc.

Answer (score 26):

> 投稿する (toukou suru)

can be use for those cases, like

> - ブログに投稿する (post on the blog)
> - コメント投稿する (post a comment)
> - 写真/画像を投稿する (upload or post a photo)
> - 動画を投稿する　(upload or post a video)

and for blog entry 更新する can also be used

> ブログを更新する (update the blog) like ブログ更新したなう　(just updated the blog) on twitter

and for comments and piece of information 投げる could be one option

> コメント投げた　(gave a comment)

Comment: +1 Great example sentences. I would also add 載せる, as in ブログに載せる.

Answer (score 12):

投稿する(とうこうする) is the one you'd most likely see for referring to posting on forums. It means that you've contributed or submitted something.

更新する(こうしんする) is for blog entries and means you've renewed or updated something.

アップする and うpする (or just うp) is for uploading (be they photos, videos, or just generic files). As you'd imagine, the latter is an Internet shorthand which you'll likely encounter on photo sites or something like YouTube and Nico Nico Douga. To thank the uploader for some content that was uploaded, you would say:

> うp主ありがとう！

Watch for this line when browsing video sites, you'll see it a lot. :)

Answer (score 5):

I've heard する　like Blogするand アップする when referencing putting stuff on the internet.

Comment: +1 for アップする, at least in the case of pictures

Comment: works for file uploads as well

Comment: I think I've personally seen 「うｐ」 more than 「アップ」. The latter just seems so... stiff.

Comment: we use アップ at my work in any formal documents we make... but then again that may be the definition of stiff.  conversely i see うｐ as childish like writing u for you...  but i'm old and what do i know.

Answer (score 2):

Normal common way of saying it is:
載せる　・　のせる

More formal version:
掲載する　・　けいさい